# Write code in return statement, add dot to string

Tags: javascript, string, replace, return

Could you help mee to write a code that as soon it sees in string "\n" would replace it with "\n\t\t\t" and add a dot after p. 
from actual text = "\t\tp\nLorem ipsum\nMid magnis\nTristique mauris proin" to 
Expected: "\t\tp.\n\t\t\tLorem ipsum\n\t\t\tMid magnis\n\t\t\tTristique mauris proin"

I know for replacement I can use text.replace(/(?:\n)/g, "\n\t\t\t") but how to add dot after p. because all this operation a have to do in return statement att once.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
var res = text.replace(/(\n)/g, "$1\t\t\t").replace(/(p)/g, "$1.")
```